# Wordpress Media Thumbnail Settings - Apply changes to custom image

Tags: php, wordpress

I've registered new image size by using:

```
add_action("init", "addcustomthumbsize");
function addcustomthumbsize() {
    if (function_exists('add_image_size')) {
        add_image_size('custom-thumb', 150, 150, true); 
    }
}

add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'custom_thumbnail');
function custom_thumbnail($sizes) {
    $addsizes = array(
        "custom-thumb" => __("Custom thumbnail")
    );
    $newsizes = array_merge($sizes, $addsizes);
    return $newsizes;
}
```

I'd like users to be able to crop images through the Media Library and apply the changes to this custom thumbnail only.

The problem is I can't figure out how to add the custom thumbnail to the list in Media Library -> Edit Image -> Thumbnail Settings.
Currently the only available options are:

- All image sizes
- Thumbnail
- All sizes except thumbnail

Thanks

Comment: Seems impossible to achieve, there's [no useful hook there](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/image-edit.php#L164)... :/

Answer (score 0):

Currently this feature is not built into WordPress. If you are interested or need this feature now (although not recommended due to instability and modification of core files), there is development of this future feature/fix at the Make Wordpress Core:

- [ticket 19889](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19889)
- [ticket 22100](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22100)

The issues of why this feature is not currently available is also described in the comments. Wordpress 3.7 may contain this fix.